# Listing columns in table from existing schema with SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, automap

The (I think) simple question - how can I use SQL Alchemy automap extension to list the columns of a table within a schema - importantly - of an existing mysql database??

This is what I have been attempting (trying to follow docs here:
 [Automap](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html)):

```
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine)

Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()
```

From this point, I can 'see' all the tables (e.g. `Base.classes.table1`, `Base.classes.table2` etc), and can 'see' the columns in a particular table as attributes of each table (e.g. `Base.classes.table1.column1`, `Base.classes.column2`).

The question is basically is there a simple way to list the columns in the tables? (or indeed the tables in the schema?).. Something analagous to `SHOW COLUMNS IN 'table1'`... Maybe I am missing somethings obvious / basic here.

A perhaps related comment - I have been both a mysql admin/user and a python user for several years now, and I am only just dipping my toes into the ORM world. Maybe I am just slow, but I am finding the docs for SQL Alchemy to be pretty impenetrable - there is seems to be mountains and mountains of documentation (and whole new vocabularly to use)... or maybe I am just thinking about ORM in completely the wrong way - so any basic  guides etc - that aren't from SQL Alchemy - would be appreciated. Perhaps something along the lines of "SQL Alchemy  for SQL users" - if such a thing exists..

Comment: To your related comment, SQLAlchemy is a huge library, so it follows that the documentation is vast. Try starting from the basics, like the [Object Relational Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html), teaching yourself a useful subset first.

Comment: Note that what you see are not tables, but the automatically generated mapped classes, which the attribute `Base.classes` hints at.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is basically contained in the question link to by Ilja Everilä. 
Will mark as duplicate - but here is the direct answer to my question:

`Base.classes.table1.__table__.columns`  will provide you with columns information (as an SQL Alchemy `ImmutableColumnCollection` object, which has a handful of methods).

One of those methods will yield a list of column names, specifically:

`Base.classes.table1.__table__.columns.keys()`

...Basically the main thing I was missing was the "magic" `__table__` attribute/object.